# Разблокировка кнопки на сайте с двумя условиями

Tags: javascript, html, функции, input, recaptcha

Я честно говоря совсем ещё не изучала JS, но он очень понадобился для обеспечения функционала одного момента в сайте, а именно: "возник вопрос в том, как сделать кнопку разблокированной после соблюдения двух условий: все поля заполнены и введена капча".
Я смогла сделать на JS проверку для каждого условия отдельно, вот так:

```
function check() {
    var inp1 = document.getElementById('FirstNameInput'),
        inp2 = document.getElementById('LastNameInput'),
        inp3 = document.getElementById('PhoneInput');
        document.getElementById('send').disabled = inp1.value && inp2.value && inp3.value ? false : "disabled";
    }

function btnenabl() {
        document.getElementById('send').removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
```

Кнопка:

```
<button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-outline-primary border-2 text-nowrap me-2" disabled="disabled" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#">Отправить</button>
```

По отдельности всё работает...
Подскажите, как мне их объединить?

Comment: Где находится кнопка?  В форме? Если в форме, то поля ввода находятся там-же? Или просто где-то в документе? Что не работает? Что означает "по отдельности всё работает"? Что Вы хотите объединить? Где вызывается `btnenabl()`? Лучше добавьте воспроизводимый пример с помощью сниппета кода...

Comment: Нет: кнопка находится в отдельном <div>, а форма находится в другом <div> - они независимы друг от друга. Если все поля заполнить, то кнопка разблокируется. Аналогично и с решением капчи. Я хочу чтобы при заполнении полей, но при нерешённой капче кнопка была заблокирована. Сейчас если я заполню поля или решу капчу она разблокируется, хотелось бы соблюдение обоих условий. Вызывается в блоке <script> перед закрывающем тэгом </head>

Comment: Какая капча?! Где она в приведённом Вами примере кода? Старайтесь уточняющие детали добавлять в вопрос. Поймите, пожалуйста, что все здесь присутствующие не знают Вашу проблему/задачу/код и для того, чтобы Вам помочь, необходимо понять что у Вас есть, что не работает и что нужно в итоге. Воспользуйтесь снипеттом кода в редакторе (`Ctrl + M`) и создайте воспроизводимый пример. Если по каким-то причинам встроенных возможностей сниппета Вам не хватает, то воспользуйтесь сторонними сервисами (например [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net)), а здесь укажите ссылку.

Comment: А она отдельно идёт: <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="мой ключ" data-callback="btnenabl">

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать так

```js
function check() {
    const inp1 = document.getElementById('FirstNameInput'),
        inp2 = document.getElementById('LastNameInput'),
        inp3 = document.getElementById('PhoneInput');
        document.getElementById('send').disabled = inp1.value && inp2.value && inp3.value ? false : "disabled";
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="FirstNameInput" oninput="check()" />
  <input id="LastNameInput" oninput="check()" />
  <input id="PhoneInput" oninput="check()" />
  <button id="send" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```